# How to solve $\sin(x)=1/x$ over the interval $[0,2\pi]$ without graphing

Tags: trigonometry

I was trying to solve the problem $x\sin(x)=1$ (where $x$ is a real number from $0$ to $2\pi$) and I hit a block when I got to the point $\sin(x)=1/x$. I want to solve this without graphing but do not know if there is a way to. I was thinking that it might involve an interpretation of $\sin(x)$ in terms of Euler's formula but did not know how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without graphing or inspection, consider the Taylor expansion built around $x=0$
$$x\sin(x)=x^2-\frac{x^4}{6}+\frac{x^6}{120}-\frac{x^8}{5040}+\frac{x^{10}}{362880}-\frac{x^{12}}{39916800}+O\left(x^{14}\right)$$ Now, use series reversion to get
$$x=\sqrt y\left(1+\frac{y}{12}+\frac{29 y^2}{1440}+\frac{263 y^3}{40320}+\frac{23479
   y^4}{9676800}+\frac{3749651 y^5}{3832012800}+O\left(y^6\right)\right)$$ Make $y=1$ to get, as an *approximation*, 
$$x=\frac{853312507}{766402560}\approx 1.1134$$ while the exact solution (obtained using Newton method) is  $1.1142$. Not too bad (I hope).

This being "close" to $\frac \pi 3$, I computed the value of $x\sin(x)-1$ for $x=\frac {2\pi} 3$ and for $x=\pi$ and supposed that there is root close to $\pi$. Let us do the same
$$x\sin(x)=-\pi  (x-\pi )-(x-\pi )^2+\frac{1}{6} \pi  (x-\pi )^3+\frac{1}{6} (x-\pi
   )^4-\frac{1}{120} \pi  (x-\pi )^5-\frac{1}{120} (x-\pi )^6+\frac{\pi  (x-\pi
   )^7}{5040}+\frac{(x-\pi )^8}{5040}-\frac{\pi  (x-\pi )^9}{362880}-\frac{(x-\pi
   )^{10}}{362880}+O\left((x-\pi )^{11}\right)$$
Series reversion again to get
$$x=\pi -\frac{y}{\pi }-\frac{y^2}{\pi ^3}-\frac{\left(12+\pi ^2\right) y^3}{6 \pi
   ^5}-\frac{\left(15+2 \pi ^2\right) y^4}{3 \pi ^7}+O\left(y^5\right)$$
Making again $y=1$ gives, as an *approximation*,
$$x=-\frac{30+16 \pi ^2+7 \pi ^4+6 \pi ^6-6 \pi ^8}{6 \pi ^7} \approx 2.7753$$
while the exact solution (obtained using Newton method) is  $2.7726$. Not too bad (I hope).

**Edit**

Just out of curiosity, wondered what we could get useing the superb approximation
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ proposed, more than 1,400 years ago, by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician.

Using it, we need to solve the cubic equation
$$16 x^3-4(4 \pi -1) x^2-4 \pi  x+5 \pi ^2=0$$ Using the trigonometric method for three real roots, the solutions are given by
$$x_k=\frac{1}{12} \left(4\pi-1+2 P \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \pi  k-\cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{Q}{P^3}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$ with
$$P=\sqrt{1+4 \pi +16 \pi ^2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad Q=-1-6 \pi -246 \pi ^2+64 \pi ^3$$ The decimal representation of the required roots are $1.1149$ and $2.7739$ which are much better than what was obtained above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "closed-form" solution to equations such as this.
You can use numerical methods, such as Newton's method, to find  approximate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no colsed for m for this equation, numerically, you can solve it using differnt methods (Newton, bissection, ...).

However I suggest to solve it using the Taylor expansion of the sin function. It involves finding the roots of polynomials.